# Excel Macro VBA Deleting specific data from a month's spreadsheet

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I am very new to Visual Basic Applications and I am looking to know how to format specific part of the spreadsheet using macros .

I attached a screenshot and I want to delete the data starting from 12AM till 8AM for a month of such typical data. Please let me know how to do much using Excel Macro.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is solution where you can provide range for loop that checks cells in this range and then deletes entire rows after checking all cells:

```
Sub remove_rows()

    'range of dates to be checked
    Dim target_range As Range
    Set target_range = Range("A1:A10")

    'range of cells to be removed
    Dim remove_range As Range

    Dim from_time As String
    Dim to_time As String

    from_time = "19:37:38"
    to_time = "22:01:38"

    'loop to get all cells
    For Each cell In target_range

        If TimeValue(cell) > from_time And TimeValue(cell) < to_time Then

            Debug.Print TimeValue(cell)

            If remove_range Is Nothing Then
                Set remove_range = cell
            Else
                Set remove_range = Union(remove_range, cell)
            End If

        End If

    Next cell

    'just for debuging puposes (delete this line later)
    remove_range.Select

    'remove all rows (change it if you want to shift cells...)
    remove_range.EntireRow.Delete

    Set remove_range = Nothing

End Sub
```

I created series of dates in my range A1:A10 (use yours here). And here you can see which rows would be deleted:

[image]

Also change time criteria:
from_time = "19:37:38" and to_time = "22:01:38"